# Which option is better to search in two tables in varchar columns?

Tags: sql-server, string-searching

I have a performance problem with searching in varchar columns in SQL Server 2016. Considering these tables have plenty of rows, for example 60000 rows each one.

**Tables**

```sql
CREATE TABLE Persons (
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
CityID int)

CREATE TABLE Cities(
CityID int,
CityName varchar(255))
```

**Code**

I have a problem like this:

```
SELECT p.PersonID, p.FirstName , c.CityID,c.CityName  FROM PERSONS p
JOIN CITIES c ON c.CityID = p.CityID 
WHERE 
     p.FirstName like '%'+@search+'%' 
  OR p.LastName  like '%'+@search+'%' 
  OR c.CityName  like '%'+@search+'%'
```

Possible Solutions in my mind:

1. Creating a full text index for each table.
2. Creating Columnstore indexes.
3. Replicating the columns to another table and searching there.

I've searched in books like: "SQL Server 2012 Query Peformance Tunning" and "Expert Peformance Indexing for SQL Server 2012". And of course, a lot of sites and blogs on the internet.I would appreciate another suggestions to solve this issue.

Comment: 60k really isn't that many - what is your current performance and what is your target? How big will this table ultimately grow? How would solution #3 help? Can you not narrow down what field the user is searching for at all, at least separate out first/last name vs city?

Comment: The Persons table can grow to 500k for each costumer. I'm looking for someway to replace the operator 'like' because it's causing a full-scan for costusmer. I can put all searchable fields in a indexed view and creating a full text index, this is for solution #3. It's a generic search and I have to return all rows with match and both tables.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm voting this as a dup of another question, where I answered about using a Full Text Index, which is probably your best bet here IMO. Of course, you'll need to test for yourself!

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Paul White wrote [this article](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search) about using a trigram wildcard string search in place of the LIKE operator. It's quite an in-depth article, but it's probably the best you'll find on the subject (like a lot of what Paul White writes). I've implemented it in a test environment and it really is lightning fast compared to the LIKE operator.

Comment: While that is a great article, using it on names which can easily be < 3 characters (AJ, Ed, Al, etc.) might disqualify it right off the bat.